# Storing Values by Negative Index

Tags: java

I am actually working on a chunk system for my infinity size world map,
and I just realized that I will use *negative* `x` and `y` coordinates.

So, my question is what would be the best solution for storing an infinity amount of chunk objects indexed by `x` AND `y`.

Up until now I was using this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Chunk>> chunks = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Chunk>>();
//...
chunk = chunks.get(x).get(y);
version = chunks.get(x).get(y).getVersion();
```

But when negative indexes kick in, the whole concept just failed.

Comment: If you want an infinite number of chunks, you'll probably need more than 2^31 indices; that number, while quite big, is much smaller than infinity. If you need just a _lot_ of chunks, how many, and how many will you keep in memory at once? Do you really need the negatives, or will just the positive half suffice? This question needs to be flushed out a bit.

Comment: @yshavit i dont think a player would ever reach 2^31 in lifetime because 1 chunk = 512 pix² and the player moves at maxspeed 64 pix/s so the player would need 544,7 years to reach if nothing blocks his path. But about store this amouth of data I'm not sure myself...anyway what do you mean by "positive half suffice"?

Comment: I meant that, for instance, you could map the range -50 to 50, to 0 to 100.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use maps instead of lists:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Chunk>> chunks = new TreeMap<>();

// ...

Chunk chunk = chunks.get(x).get(y);
```

Obviously, this solution only works until you run out of memory. I'm having a hard time understanding the infinite nature of your map. Will you just be generating new tiles/chunks when you get close to the boundary?

Comment: Yep. The server generats a new Chunk when the Client is asking for a Chunk that not yet exists. Thats why i used ArrayList until now.

Comment: In that case, you will either need to restrict your map (making it no longer infinite), or put it in some form of storage (file, database, ...) and only load the relevant parts in memory. That is, unless you have an unlimited server farm with unlimited memory ;)

Comment: I just tried out the TreeMap and till now it looks like its fits needs well. And i'll also consider the possibillity of unloading chunk for the sake of memory. Thank you and all others ;)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to store an **infinite** amount of data in an array? 
Probably you need something better than that. You cannot keep all the information in memory so you need a better data structure that allow you to have only a bit of information available in memory and keep the remaining part on the disk.

Comment: I have not yet tested it out but that point is also always bothering me because a chunk contains 16*16 tiles and a tile contains everything that is on it (ground,objects,event and all infos about height,walkable....etc) so it might comes to a lot of data in the future ô.o